# directed graph, pentagon and tikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

How could I draw this directed graph using LaTeX?

[image]

I know the following code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphs.standard}

\tikzgraphsset{declare={polygon_n}{[clique]\foreach\x in\tikzgraphV{\x/}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\tikz\graph[clockwise, nodes={circle, node distance=4cm, fill=blue, inner sep=1}] 
{ polygon_n[n=5] };
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need the rotation you can use `subgraph C_n [n=5, counterclockwise]`, provided by the `graphs.standard` library to get the basic shape. Then it's just a matter of setting the style of the nodes and edges, as in the example below:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs, graphs.standard}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\graph [
  nodes={draw, circle, fill=red!20}, % style of nodes
  edges={-latex}, % style of lines between nodes
  radius=2cm % size of graph
  ] {
    subgraph C_n [n=5, counterclockwise]
  };

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```